# Homotopic maps induce isomorphic pullbacks of a principal bundle. How functorial can this be?

Tags: algebraic-topology

More precisely, I'm trying to show that the groupoid $\mathscr{B}G(X)$ of principal $G$-bundles over $X$ and isomorphisms is equivalent to $\Pi_1(BG^X)$.  It seems like the right direction to try to construct my functor is $\Pi_1(BG^X) \rightarrow \mathscr{B}G(X)$, since given an actual $G$-bundle over $X$ I'm not sure how I should expect to make a choice of map $X\rightarrow BG$ (as opposed to just a choice of equivalence class up to homotopy).

So, to an object $(f:X\rightarrow BG)\in \Pi_1(BG^X)$ we of course associate $f^*EG\in \mathscr{B}G(X)$.  Then, given a morphism $([H]:X\times I \rightarrow BG)\in \Pi_1(BG^X)(f_0,f_1)$ (i.e. an equivalence class up to homotopy of paths from $f_0$ to $f_1$ in $BG^X$) We then use the lifting property, which can be done $G$-equivariantly, to get an isomorphism $f_0^*EG \rightarrow f_1^*EG$.

The problem is that unless I've got something a bit stronger this isn't going to be functorial: the composition of two homotopy-classes-of-paths in $BG^X$ won't necessarily give rise to the composite isomorphism.  It seems like what I want is a connection that'll tell me what "horizontal" means, but this is definitely not part of the data I'm given.

Bonus question: This doesn't work for topological groups (let $G$ be connected and take $X=pt$).  How can this be repaired -- is there a good alternative description of $\mathscr{B}G(X)$ in that case?

Comment: Wowwwww.  Of course you're right.  It's hard to believe it but I guess all the fancy talk (I didn't even say "stack"!) got in the way of good ol' Hatcher Chapter One.

Comment: Feel free to post this as an answer, or I'll CW it and answer it myself.

Comment: OK (and what happens for connected G and X=pt, BTW?)

Comment: $\pi_1(BG)=\pi_0(G)=1$, which would mean that a $G$-bundle over a point has no automorphisms.  That's not right.

Comment: Well, $\Pi_1(BG^X)$ describes not $(Bun,Iso)$ but $(Bun,\pi_0(Iso))$, I believe. Perhaps, you need $\Pi_\infty(BG^X)$ to get all $BG(X)$, in some sense.

Comment: Oh, I like that.  It sounds reasonable; I mean, $\Pi_\infty$ doesn't throw away any information, so morally that ought to be the right thing.  This seems to take us into the world of higher stacks and all that stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is discrete, $EG\to BG$ is a covering, so the lifting is unique. Since composition of liftings is always a lifting of composition, this implies functoriality.